# Relationship of cartesian and parametric form of a line in R3

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametric

When one converts the parametric representation of a line in R3 to its cartesian form doesn't that create some ambiguity? If I look at the plane expressed by that cartesian equation and the previously defined line that was converted to cartesian form do they geometrically relate to each other at all?

Comment: This question is too vague, do you have an equation or equations in mind?

Comment: For example the parametric form of the line going through the origin with direction (1,1,1) and its cartesian equation. Does the plane that shares the same cartesian equation and the line I described relate anyhow?

Comment: The cartesian equation of a line is three equations or you could define it as the intersection of 2 planes. So I don't know what you mean by "its cartesian equation" and "the plane". What, for your line, is your cartesian equation and plane?

Comment: $x=k \\
y=k \\
z =k\\
\\
x-y-z=0
$

Comment: On the line, $x-y-z = -k$ so I don't see how that line relates to that plane. There are an infinite number of planes this line does lie in e.g. $2x-y-z=0$ (then rotate that plane about the line)